# How do I connect to the internet with the Ubuntu server with only wireless networks

Tags: wireless

I need help to connect my Ubuntu Server to the internet over just wireless (Its the latest verison)

Answer (score 2):

By default, Ubuntu server edition does not include the required packages *wpa_supplicant* and *wireless-tools*. To install them, with a temporary working internet connection by tethering, ethernet or whatever means possible, do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install wpasupplicant wireless-tools
```

Several dependencies will also be installed.

Next, find the interface name for your wireless device:

```
iwconfig
```

Your interface name may be something like wlp3s0 or wlo1 or similar.

Next, edit your netplan file to add your exact details. A template can be found here:

```
cat /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/wireless.yaml
```

You can find the file that should be edited in `/etc/netplan` For example:

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
```

Fill in the exact details as outlined in the template. Netplan is very specific about spacing and indentation. It accepts spaces but not tabs. Proofread carefully twice. Save (Ctrl+o folloed by Enter) and exit (Ctrl+x) the text editor nano.

Follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

If there are no mistakes, you should connect immediately and automatically on boot.