# Wpa_supplicant won't install on Server 16

Tags: server, wireless, wpa-supplicant

Update: no solution has been found, so far.

I want to test Big Blue Button (videoconferencing) but Server 16's kernel doesn't support my tablet's wifi adapter so I installed a newer kernel with the three .deb files (linux-headers, image and modules), rebooted, and then my card's recognized, but when I try to install wpa_supplicant.deb along with its dependencies that don't come with Server 16, I get a bunch of "package X will break package y" and "package x with break locales" errors, and I can't run Server 16 on a VM because I don't have enough RAM (until I get real server hardware). What can I do?

Comment: Where did you download the .deb file? Here? https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/wpasupplicant

Comment: Either from there or from https://pkgs.org. Don't remember but I can go through it again. Is there a way to download a .deb and all its dependencies without doing it manually?

Comment: The link I gave is preferred. Many of the dependencies are probably already installed. Check: `sudo dpkg -s libc6 | grep Status` Substitute all of the dependencies from the link I gave. Without a temporary internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, I know of no easier way. You will also need *wireless-tools*. Possibly helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1256811/how-do-i-connect-to-the-internet-with-the-ubuntu-server-with-only-wireless-netwo/

Comment: Ok, but none of the errors pointed to packages missing or being too outdated (I got those errors before which is why I went to download the dependencies); apt just said that they'd break. Is it because the versions I tried to install were too new for the existing packages (wpa_supplicant dependencies that were already preinstalled), and that I should just purge all preinstalled wpa_supplicant dependencies and install the new versions?

Comment: I would try to install wpasupplicant *alone* and see what the errors are. Let's try to correct them one at a time. Please post the result.

Comment: Ok. Before I get to that step, upgrading from kernel 4.4.0-something (that Server 16.04.7 comes with) to 5.4.61 (latest long term according to kernel.org) is the right/best step, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112540/discussion-between-daniel-and-chili555).